# Indy IdHttp Proxy, which protocols Support?

Tags: delphi, proxy, indy10

I am using indy idhttp to work with telegram api,my code is something like this:

```
  LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  idHttp.ReadTimeout := 30000;
  idHttp.IOHandler:=LHandler;
  LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  idHttp.HandleRedirects := true;
  //Proxy Code...
  idHttp.Post( API + msg, Params, Stream);
```

my code works just fine,but the problem is because of censorship and filtering in my country ,i have to use VPN Services such as AnyConnect,L2TP,...
Now my question is how can i use Indy ProxyParams to bypass censorship and post data,of course I know that i have to add below code before idhttp.post but i can't figure out which protocols does it supports or which VPN services should i use?
Thanks in Advance.

```
  idHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyServer:='xxxxxx';
  idHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyUsername:='user';
  idHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword:='pass';
  idHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyPort:=xxx;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property only supports HTTP-based proxies that use the `CONNECT` verb to tunnel TCP connections.

For other types of proxies, you have to use the `TIdIOHandlerSocket.TransparentProxy` property instead.  For instance, to use a SOCKS proxy, assign a `TIdSocksInfo` component as the `TransparentProxy`.

VPNs are different than proxies. VPNs are handled at the networking layer, not at the application layer. You have to connect to a VPN from outside of your app first, then you can use your app normally, connecting it to the target server through the VPN network. If your OS only has 1 network installed, this is usually handled automatically for you. If your OS has multiple networks installed, or if you just want to be explicit about it, then you can tell `TIdHTTP` which network connection to use by setting its `BoundIP` property to the *local* IP address of the desired network.